# OS X - supporting AFNetworking 2 in 10.8 + and AFNetworking 1 in 10.7?

Tags: afnetworking, afnetworking-2

Is this possible to do?  Would there be a way to include both libraries and use conditional headers?  What would the cocoa pod file look like?